# How can I use Firestore data in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-firestore

I have firebase set up and I want to use the data that is retrieved from Firestore. My Firestore looks like this:

[image]

my function that gets Firestore data:

```
export const getQuestionsAndScheduelesFromFS = async () => {
    const db = getFirestore();
    const docRefQuestions = doc(db, "questions2022", "question01");
    const docSnap = await getDoc(docRefQuestions);


    if (docSnap.exists()) {
        console.log("FS questions 2022", docSnap.data());

        return docSnap.data();
    } else {
        console.log("No such data: QUESTIONS2022!");

        return docSnap.data()
    }
}
```

and this is how my data shows up in the console.log:
[image]

[image]

how can I use/ unwrap my question and alternative that I get from Firestore? alternatives is an array and question is a string.

What I want to do is to display the data inside a  component.

this is my first time using Firestore with react native and I really do need help, thank you :)

Comment: What exactly are trying to show on the screen with that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you just wan't to show the data you get from firebase. On the screen with react-native.

This below will fetch the data from firebase store that data in the useState hook, and then show the question on the screen. Please read about **useState** and **useEffect** hook it will help you greatly.

```js
export default function App() {
   // If you ever wan't state that changes throughout the app use the useState hook
   const [data,setData] = React.useState(null); 

  // Runs once the screen loads
  React.useEffect(()=>{
     const fetch = async = ()=>{ 
        const fetchedData = await getQuestionsAndScheduelesFromFS();
        setData(fetchedData);
     }
     fetch();
  },[]) 

  // Show blank screen or whatever you want while data is waiting to be initialized from the firebase data 
  if (data===null){
     return <></>
  } 
  

  return (
    <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems:"center",}}>
         <Text> {data.question}</Text>
   </View>
  )

}
```

Comment: I am going to edit my question but yes, I just wanted to display the data on the screen, thank you! this worked for me!